# How to add ssh key using JGit in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jgit, jsr223

I'm trying to do a load testing on a Bitbucket server using JMeter.
I referred this link [Jmeter and Bitbucket server load testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679039/jmeter-and-bitbucket-server-load-testing), but I'm not sure how to pass the ssh-key details using JGit in JSR223 Sampler in JMeter.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

JGit uses [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) library for Git connectivity via SSH channel therefore you need to call [JSch.addIdentity() function](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#addIdentity-java.lang.String-) and provide the path to your private/public key/password.

Example code:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.TransportConfigCallback
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.*
import org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS

CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository()
cloneCommand.setURI("your Git SSH URL")
cloneCommand.setDirectory(new File('/path/to/local/folder'))
SshSessionFactory sshSessionFactory = new JschConfigSessionFactory() {
    @Override
    protected JSch createDefaultJSch(FS fs) throws JSchException {
        JSch defaultJSch = super.createDefaultJSch(fs);
        defaultJSch.addIdentity("/path/to/your/private/key");
        return defaultJSch;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(OpenSshConfig.Host host, Session session) {
        SshTransport sshTransport = (SshTransport) transport;
        sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory(sshSessionFactory);
    }
}
cloneCommand.setTransportConfigCallback(new TransportConfigCallback() {
    @Override
    void configure(Transport transport) {
        SshTransport sshTransport = (SshTransport) transport;
        sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory(sshSessionFactory);
    }
})
cloneCommand.call()
```

More information:

- [JGit Authentication Explained](https://www.codeaffine.com/2014/12/09/jgit-authentication/)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)
- [JSch - Examples - UserAuthPubKey.java](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/UserAuthPubKey.java.html)